# Inconsistent workflow rule behavior

Tags: workflow, workflowoutboundmessage

I have an external service that needs to get updated when an `Event` record is updated. So I set up a workflow rule:

`Evaluate the rule when a record is: created and every time it's edited`

`Run this rule if the formula evaluates to true:`

and for the sake of testing the formula is just "`true`" with the intention of it always running when a record is edited.

For the outbound message, I put in my endpoint URL. And I selected a few of the fields I'm interested in, some custom some standard.

When first testing it by editing a field on an existing event, it worked as expected by pinging my endpoint right after the event was saved. Then it begins to work inconsistently. Either it won't ping my endpoint for 5-10 minutes after the record was saved, or it won't send a ping at all.

Then if I try editing another record, it works instantly after the first edit, but the same behavior occurs where if I keep making changes it stops sending updates to my endpoint.

I've also noticed sometimes it will send the same outbound message 2, 3 or 4 times even though an event was only edited once.

Why is this inconsistent behavior happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Either it won't ping my endpoint for 5-10 minutes after the record was saved

This happens if you exceed the hourly limit or there's a large queue of items that need to be sent.

> or it won't send a ping at all.

If the record was still in the queue, it wouldn't be added again; all the updates should be consolidated into a single update.

> I've also noticed sometimes it will send the same outbound message 2, 3 or 4 times even though an event was only edited once.

This usually happens if your endpoint fails to send an ACK (acknowledgement) back in a timely fashion. Salesforce presumes the message was not processed and does so again.

If you're really having problems with it, you might want to go with the [Change API](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_object_change_tracking_example_streaming_api.htm&type=5), which is much more "reliable" and doesn't suffer from many of the shortcomings of the Outbound Messaging framework.

Comment: OK that does explain the repeated messages since my endpoint does not send any special acknowledgement other than a status 200 OK response. But not the delay since I've experienced a delay after only one edit. Also unrelated but does the workflow rule framework trigger outbound messages when records are updated through the API? Like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @rosghub Yes, workflow rules always trigger except for bulk updates in the metadata (e.g. if you change a picklist value globally, it wouldn't trigger the workflow rule). I don't have enough experience with Outbound Messages in general, just what I've seen from the docs and some old-school experiments back in the day. I'll see if I can't make a Heroku mockup and try to replicate the issue.